# CSS3 Dropdown Menu (touch device or mouse compatible)

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation, touch

This may be rather basic, but I wanted to experiment and learn with some of the upcoming CSS3 techniques. I wasn't able to come up with an HTML/CSS only solution, and I had to work longer than I'd like to admit to get to a point where this menu works as intended on desktop or mobile.

The main lesson I learned is forget about using `:hover` to control actions. It's worthless on mobile, and having the function on click in desktop isn't that bad, and is probably the better practice anyway.

I haven't tested in a lot of env, but more than a few. It seems to work pretty well in modern browsers. Let me know how I can improve!

[GitHub](https://github.com/agraymd/Animated-Profile-Menu)

[Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tddfevhv/1/)

```js
//click to open menu
$('.follow button').click(function(){
    $('.addClass').toggleClass("profile-container");
});
```

```css
/*RESET*/
 /* http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ 
    v2.0 | 20110126
    License: none (public domain)
 */

 html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
 h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
 a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
 del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
 small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
 b, u, i, center,
 dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
 fieldset, form, label, legend,
 table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
 article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
 figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
 menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
 time, mark, audio, video {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  vertical-align: baseline;
 }
 /* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
 article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
 footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
  display: block;
 }
 body {
  line-height: 1;
 }
 ol, ul {
  list-style: none;
 }
 blockquote, q {
  quotes: none;
 }
 blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
 q:before, q:after {
  content: '';
  content: none;
 }
 table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0;
 }
 *{
  letter-spacing: normal;
 }
/* END RESET */

/*Disables text selection*/
body{
 -webkit-touch-callout: none;
 -webkit-user-select: none;
 -moz-user-select: none;
 -ms-user-select: none;
 -o-user-select: none;
 user-select: none;
 display: table;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 background-image: url(https://i.imgsafe.org/100dde0.png); 
}
/* Text Center class */
.center{
 text-align: center;
}
/*Class that centers img elements in their container*/
img.centerImg{
 display: block;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
/*profileDropdown*/

 /* PROFILE STYLES */
 ul, li {
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
     list-style-type: none;
 }

 .container {
     margin: 0px auto 0;
     width: 378px;
 }

 .profile-container {
     position: relative;
     width: 378px;
     float: left;
 }

 .profile {
  width: 370px;
     background: #f6f6f6;
     float: left;
     padding: 4px;
     border-radius: 3px;
     -o-border-radius: 3px;
     -ms-border-radius: 3px;
     -moz-border-radius: 3px;
     -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
     -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
     -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
     -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
     -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
     transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
 }

 .avatar img {
     display: block;
     border-radius: 5px;
     -o-border-radius: 5px;
     -ms-border-radius: 5px;
     -moz-border-radius: 5px;
     -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
 }

 #portraitCaption{
  font-style: italic;
  color: #b9b9b9;
  font-size: .75em;
 }

 .follow {
     margin: 0px 0 0 0;
 }

 .follow button {
     display: block;
     width: 100%;
     border: 0;
     background: #268cde;
     color: white;
     font-weight: bold;
     font-size: 1.25em;
     padding: 7px 0;
     margin: 0;
     border-radius: 3px;
     -o-border-radius: 3px;
     -ms-border-radius: 3px;
     -moz-border-radius: 3px;
     -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
     -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
     -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
     -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
     -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
     transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
     cursor: pointer;
 }


 .follow button:hover {
     background: #3096e8;
 }

 .follow button:active {
     background: #2085d6;
 }

 .profile-list {
     overflow: hidden;
     width: 100%;
     box-sizing: border-box;
     color: #767b7e;
     font-size: 13px;
 }

 .profile-list li {
     cursor: pointer;
     background: #ffffff;
     border-top: 1px solid #e5e6e6;
 }

 .profile-list li:last-child {  
     border-radius: 0 0 3px 3px;;
     -o-border-radius: 0 0 3px 3px;
     -ms-border-radius: 0 0 3px 3px;
     -moz-border-radius: 0 0 3px 3px;
     -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 3px 3px;
 }


 .profile-list .profile {
     border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
     position: relative;
 }



 .profile-list li {
     -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
     -o-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
     transform-origin: 50% 0%;
     -webkit-transform: perspective(60px) rotateX(-90deg);
     -o-transform: perspective(60px) rotateX(-90deg);
     transform: perspective(60px) rotateX(-90deg);
     -moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
 }
 .profile-list li a{
  display: block;
  padding: 15px 10px;
 }

 .profile-container .profile-list .fourth {
     transition-delay: 0.6s;
     -o-transition-delay: 0.6s;
     transition-delay: 0.6s;
 } 

 .profile-list .first {
     -webkit-transition: 0.2s linear 0.8s;
     -o-transition: 0.2s linear 0.8s;
     transition: 0.2s linear 0.8s;
 }

 .profile-list .second {
     -webkit-transition: 0.2s linear 0.6s;
     -o-transition: 0.2s linear 0.6s;
     transition: 0.2s linear 0.6s;
 }

 .profile-list .third {
     -webkit-transition: 0.2s linear 0.4s;
     -o-transition: 0.2s linear 0.4s;
     transition: 0.2s linear 0.4s;
 }

 .profile-list .fourth {
     -webkit-transition: 0.2s linear 0.2s;
     -o-transition: 0.2s linear 0.2s;
     transition: 0.2s linear 0.2s;
 }

 .profile-container .profile-list li {
     -webkit-transform: perspective(350px) rotateX(0deg);
     -o-transform: perspective(350px) rotateX(0deg);
     transform: perspective(350px) rotateX(0deg);
     -webkit-transition: 0.2s linear 0s;
     -o-transition: 0.2s linear 0s;
     transition: 0.2s linear 0s;
 }

 .profile-container .profile-list .second {
     -webkit-transition-delay: 0.2s;
     -o-transition-delay: 0.2s;
     transition-delay: 0.2s;
 }

 .profile-container .profile-list .third {
     -webkit-transition-delay: 0.4s;
     -o-transition-delay: 0.4s;
     transition-delay: 0.4s;
 }

 .profile-list li a{
  color: #268CDE;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
 }


 .follow p{
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: Times New Roman, Serif;
  font-size: 1.25em;
 }

  .profile-list li a:hover{
  background-color: #e0e0e0;

 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
 <head>
  <meta CHARSET="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">  
  <title>Title</title>
  <meta name="Keywords" content="">
  <meta name="Description" content="">

   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
 </head>

 <body id="profileDropdown">

  <div class="container">
   <div class="profile">
    <img id="profilePicture" class="avatar" src="#" alt="Your Name Portrait" height="416" width="370" >
    <span id="portraitCaption">Your Name</span>
   </div><!-- END PROFILE SECTION -->

   <div class="addClass">
    <div class="follow"><button id="dropdownButton">Follow</button></div> 
     <nav id="dropDown" class="profile-list">
      <ul class="center">
       <li id="gitHubProfile" class="first" >
        <a href="https://github.com/agraymd" title="Follow me on GitHub!" target="_blank">GitHub</a>
       </li>
       <li class="second">
        <a href="" title="Connect on LinkedIn" target="_blank">LinkedIn</a>
       </li>
       <li class="third">
        <a href="" title="Email Me" target="_blank">Google</a>
       </li>
       <li class="fourth">
        <a href="" title="My Resume" target="_blank">Resume</a>
       </li>
      </ul>
     </nav>   
   </div>
  </div>







  <script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
  <script src="js/main.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
 </body>

</html>
```

Comment: In your CSS: What's the reason for giving 'body' a 'position: absolute'?

Comment: Good call, I'm not even sure lol. I think that had to do with previous styling where I was using it to center all content on the page. Removed and still works as it should.

Answer (score 2):

Your HTML formatting is messy.

- Too much Vertical White Space
- inconsistent indentation
- inconsistent new line usage

I almost thought that you were missing an end tag because the indentations weren't consistent.

Changing that, this is what it looks like:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
    <head>
        <meta CHARSET="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">        
        <title>Title</title>
        <meta name="Keywords" content="">
        <meta name="Description" content="">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    </head>
    <body id="profileDropdown">   
        <div class="container">
            <div class="profile">
                <img id="profilePicture" class="avatar" src="#" alt="Your Name Portrait" height="416" width="370" >
                <span id="portraitCaption">Your Name</span>
            </div><!-- END PROFILE SECTION -->
            <div class="addClass">
                <div class="follow">
                    <button id="dropdownButton">Follow</button>
                </div>  
                <nav id="dropDown" class="profile-list">
                    <ul class="center">
                        <li id="gitHubProfile" class="first" >
                            <a href="https://github.com/agraymd" title="Follow me on GitHub!" target="_blank">GitHub</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="second">
                            <a href="" title="Connect on LinkedIn" target="_blank">LinkedIn</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="third">
                            <a href="" title="Email Me" target="_blank">Google</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="fourth">
                            <a href="" title="My Resume" target="_blank">Resume</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>          
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
        <script src="js/main.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
    </body>
</html>
```